# bg-color attribute -- wrong color displayed

Tags: css, colors, attr

I'm currently facing a wierd issue with `bg-color` data-attribute. I'm writing an email template using **premailer** to inline my style.

---

Here is the **problem** :

```
$color_main: red;
$color_main-background: rgba($color_main, .5);

.foo {
    background: $color_main-background;
}
```

Result:

[image]

will output this :

```
<tr class="foo" bgcolor="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)">
    .
    .
    .
</tr>
```

which is *good*.

**But** my browser (*Google Chrome v. 58.0.3029.110*) translate this as :

```
tr[Attributes Style] {
    background-color: rgb(0, 80, 0);
}
```

which is *wrong*, and green.

[cfr. linked image]

[image]

---

Any idea of... why?

btw, it works well with

```
.foo {
    background: $color_main; (= red)
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Normally when dealing with email pretend it's still the early 2000s with `<font>` tags and everything (and don't keep anything in the `<head>` as it's often discarded)... it's possible it's stumbling on the alpha channel with `rgba` try `rgb(255,128,128)` or `#ff8080` as a test.

Comment: I tried to write 'rgba(red, 0.5)' (which basically what you doing). And that did not work in chrome. If you going to use rgba you have to use number, i.e. rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) (255, 0, 0 would be red)

Comment: Yep it's an Alpha chanell issue! 

It works well with simple RGB colors. But since I have multiple "themes" with different colors, I really want my code to create alpha background-color from my base color according to the theme. I guess I'll have to write my background color in HEX for each theme... Do you know any SASS function to convert RGBA to HEX ? 

But thank for your answer ! I thought I missed something

Comment: The problem is simply that `rgba(...)` is an incorrect value for the bgcolor attribute. So different browsers will display different things. (It does come out as pink in IE.) Is it really impossible to use a `style` attribute? Otherwise, you may have to find a mixin that can compute an rgb color from an rgba one.The built in function `mix` doesn't do that.